# Is it legal to use a variable in a struct initializer in C?

Tags: c, initialization, splint

The following code seems to compile fine.

```
typedef struct Test {
  int i;
  int j;
} Test;

int main() {
  int i;
  i = 0;
  Test p = {i, 1};
  printf("%d\n", p.i);
  return 0;
}
```

Splint fails with

```
example2.c:9:7: Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
           parseerrors.
```

(This is the line `Test p = {i, 1};`)

Is this illegal C, or is this a bug in splint?

(I want to do this because I want p to be `const`, although the failure seems to happen even when I remove the `const` modifier. If I move the declaration and initialization of `i` onto one line, the problem also seems to go away.)

Comment: C99 [allows it](http://ideone.com/MmU9X9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is legal since C99 as that is an `auto`matic variable. It is not legal, however, for global and `static` variables. gcc also allows this for pre-C99 as an extension (still `auto` only, of course).

I generally recommend to use at least C99-compatible compilers, as there are some subtle differences to the earlier standard and C99 introduces many useful features, like C++ line-comments, `_Bool`, etc.

Note: `p` is initialized at run-time and each time the function is called (`main` is normally called only once, but the rule also applies here). No matter if you make it `const` or not. In general, for `const` variables (sic!), it is better to also have them `static` or global to save the run-time overhead. OTOH, this (see above) disallows a variable initializer.

Comment: It's legal for `register` variables, too.

Comment: @FUZxxl: `register` implies `auto`.

Comment: In reality p is dependent on user input, and so I don't think it really makes sense to make it `static` (although as it's in the main function it doesn't make any difference, as you say.) I don't mean "this is constant for all calls to this function" otherwise I might have well declared it outside the function. I just want to pre vent it accidentally being modified subsequently in the function.

Comment: @GeorgeSimms: That was more a general addenum. Rmember, there might be other users reading this and wonder why it does not work (although all pieces of the puzzle are given before).

Comment: @Olaf OK. But I think it is still legitimate, semantically, to have a non-static const

Comment: @GeorgeSimms: I did not say (nor imply) the opposite. And I'm perfectly fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

Initializers like these are a C99 feature. I don't know splint, but the splint manual is stuck in the year 2003 -- which means there's a solid probability splint just doesn't speak C99.